# Error: - Setting up a chrome instance when running exec(npx command)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

I am building a firefox add-on built with react and node js, and currently trying to integrate with is-website-vulnerable api for inspection. with the node.js code as follows,

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');



const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

function checkVulnerabilities(url, callback) {
    //url = convertToWww(url);
    exec(`npx is-website-vulnerable ${url}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`Execution error: ${error}`);
            callback({ error: `Execution error: ${error}` });
            return;
        }

        // Check if stderr is actually an error or just a log
        if (stderr && !stdout.includes("Auditing completed")) {
            console.error(`Error: ${stderr}`);
            callback({ error: `Error: ${stderr}` });
            return;
        }

        callback({ result: stdout }); // Pass the result back via callback
    });
}

app.post('/checkVulnerabilities', (req, res) => {
    const { url } = req.body;
    checkVulnerabilities(url, (data) => {
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

I get the following error message. Error: - Setting up a chrome instance
✔ Set up completed in 0.53 seconds!

- Auditing...
  ✔ Auditing completed in 4.26 seconds!

it works fine when I run the command directly from the command line.

how can I run the command without error?

Comment: The required string is being printed from `Error: ${stderr}` but the code is checking for it via `stdout.includes`